# What is the difference between `new` and `new()` for a struct in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, struct, language-features, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

In some code, I recently saw a struct like this:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
    int numberOne;
    int numberTwo;
} MYSTRUCT;
```

Later, I tried instantiating one of these structs using

```
MyStruct *pStruct = new MyStruct();
```

which worked fine with Visual Studio 2010, but failed with an obscure linker error on a different compiler. It took a while until we found out that omitting the braces like this

```
MyStruct *pStruct = new MyStruct;
```

solved the issue.

So, what exactly is the difference between these two invocations and which one is the right one to use?

Comment: I think you have a redundant typedef (or a missing name for the typedef), also `new` returns a pointer not an object.

Comment: typedef struct MyStruct {
    int numberOne;
    int numberTwo;
}; is an error

Comment: @Armen: Actually none of the original lines should have compiled. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

`new MyStruct` performs *default initialization*, which in your case does nothing.

`new MyStruct()` performs *value initialization*, which in your case sets both int variables to zero.